# expect program send commands from file

Tags: linux, unix, expect

How to make **send** command of "expect" program to read from a file and use each line as argument.

I want to use a loop like structure in expect program which may look like below(NOTE:- while loop is imaginary.)

```
spawn /my/program

expect {
 -re EBtxjjmEcQTxc0SLd4TdXxjUduxCOLZBwEme2Z.*password: { 
             while read_line in FILE; 
             do 
                 send $read-line; 
             done 
}
```

How to program the while-loop part equivalent using "expect"

Comment: Please improve your question by posting some [properly formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) code you've applied to the problem. Also, include a properly-formatted sample of your **expected output** so folks understand the results you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note in your question, you were missing a close brace, and you mis-typed your variable name (`read_line` and `read-line`)

Expect is a Tcl extension, so you have all the [Tcl commands](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/) at your disposal

```
spawn /my/program
expect { 
    -re EBtxjjmEcQTxc0SLd4TdXxjUduxCOLZBwEme2Z.*password: { 
        set fh [open FILE r]
        while {[gets $fh read_line] != -1} {
            send "$read_line\r"
        } 
        close $fh
    }
}
```

If you install [tcllib](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net), you can do

```
package require fileutil
spawn /my/program
expect { 
    -re EBtxjjmEcQTxc0SLd4TdXxjUduxCOLZBwEme2Z.*password: { 
        fileutil::foreachLine read_line FILE {
            send "$read_line\r"
        } 
    }
}
```